# Reading from input stream

Tags: java, android, bitmap, inputstream, bitmapfactory

I am developing a library for my Android application where I am appending extra info to the end of a PNG image.  I am creating a *DataOutputStream* variable and writing extra info to the end of it to use when I open the PNG and convert it to a Bitmap using a *DataInputStream*.  I added a marker to distinguish when the image code finishes and my extra info starts.

The extra data is correctly being appended after the marker.  The problem is reading **ONLY** the PNG data of the *DataInputStream* to convert it into a Bitmap.  All of the *DataInputStream* is being read (even if I add a large amount of placeholder bytes before the marker).

The implementation I am using to read the PNG portion of the stream is:

*Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);*

**I am wondering if there is another way I should be implementing this to stop reading the stream after the PNG data bytes.**

If there isn't a better way, the route I would be taking is copying the input stream into an array.  I would then read all of the data until I reach the marker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a wrapper InputStream that would then report EOF before reading the entire stream.  This lets you avoid having to read the whole stream into a byte array.

```
class MarkerInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
    MarkerInputStream(InputStream in) {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        if (isAtMarker()) {
            return -1;
        }
        // may need to read from a cache depending on what isAtMarker method does.
        return super.read();
    }

    private boolean isAtMarker() {
        // logic for determining when you're at the end of the image portion
        return false;
     }
}
```